# Can not execute binary in alpine docker image

Tags: docker

I have a server written in Go and statically compiled to a binary named `main`.
This binary is put into a Docker image based on `alpine` at root `/`.

When trying to execute this binary there is an error message I can not understand:

```sh
/ # whoami
root
/ # ls -lF ./main
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       6390312 Sep 11 11:37 ./main*
/ # ./main
sh: ./main: not found
```

Can someone explain why `sh` can not find that file?

**[Edit]**

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM golang AS go-builder

COPY server ./server
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

ENV GOPATH=/go/delivery
RUN go mod download
RUN go mod verify
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags="-w -s" server/main.go

FROM alpine

COPY --from=go-builder /go/main /main

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["/main"]
```

Comment: it's hard to say without seeing the docker build command... but is the `sh`  copied to the image  with the working directory defined?

Comment: Is the binary actually statically linked?  (If you can get a copy of the executable outside the container environment, what does `file main` say?)  Can you provide a [mcve] showing how the application was built?

Comment: Alpine images use a different libc than just about everything else ([musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/), while most other distributions use glibc). Dynamic binaries compiled for glibc won't run on alpine. If you compile it on alpine, it should work fine.

Comment: I always use `go build -o myapp -ldflags '-linkmode external -w -extldflags "-static"'` if I want to run it in alpine. I think this goes towards what David was saying. Especially, a server application will rely on some parts of the system's network stack to work. That's why statically linking is important in this case.

Comment: @TheFool With these options I get `/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:58: warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking`